# 4 byte sequence 0x86 0x65 0x71 0xA5 in a little-endian architecture interpreted as a 32-bit signed integer represents what decimal?

Tags: hex, endianness

I know how to convert `0x86 0x65 0x71 0xA5` into decimals, I'm just not sure how to approach it past that point.

I assume it is (from least significant to most significant) 134 101 113 165, but what exactly do I do past this point?  I'm guessing 134,101,113,165 is not correct.  Do I need to convert anything into binary to do this?  Kind of lost conceptually.

Comment: I'm sure you remember how positional notation of numbers works, you learned that in elementary school, you've just managed to confuse yourself here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting each octet into decimal, you've essentially converted the number into base 256. You can do it that way, but it's not particularly easy. You'd have to combine the parts as follows:

134 x (256^0) + 101 x (256^1) + 113 x (256^2) + 165 x (256^3)

0x86 0x65 0x71 0xA5 as a 32-bit unsigned integer in little-endian notation would mean that the integer in hex is 0xA5716586. Then just convert from hex to decimal normally.

Either way, you will get 2,775,672,198.

However, this is a signed integer, not an unsigned integer. And because the most significant byte is A5, the most significant bit is 1. Therefore, this is a negative number.

So we need to do some math:

> FFFFFFFF - A5716586 = 5A8E9A79

So:

> A5716586 + 5A8E9A79 = FFFFFFFF

Also, in 32-bit arithmetic:

> FFFFFFFF + 1 = 0

So:

> FFFFFFFF => -1

Combining these two:

> A5716586 + 5A8E9A79 => -1
>   A5716586 = -1 -5A8E9A79 = - (5A8E9A79 + 1) = - 5A8E9A7A

Also:

> 5A8E9A7A => 1,519,295,098 (decimal)

So our final answer is -1,519,295,098

Comment: How is the result different due to being signed vs unsigned in this case?

Comment: If it was signed, it would be negative since the most significant bit is one. Sorry, let me fix that.